# Wrong tooltip language in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, tooltip, settings

My Visual Studio is running in English.
But the language in the tooltip is German. How can I change this to English too?

[image]

Comment: In VS 2015, I go to Tools/Options/Environment/International Settings. Not sure if this would change the tooltip language though. If it's set to "Same As Windows", try and set it to just "English" and see if that works.

Comment: Also, you may want to make sure there isn't an extension doing this.. You'd do this by visiting Tools > Options > Environment > Extensions and Updates

Comment: No, it is already set to "English". :/ And no extensions available.

Comment: The exception string is generated at runtime, which I believe uses your system settings.  Is your OS using a German locale?

Comment: Yes! So I have to change my windows?